# Debugging a .dtsx file

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ssis

There's a `.dtsx` file in our team folder which I can open and edit in Design view using Visual Studio 2019. This SSIS package imports an excel file to a SQL server instance. I'm new to visual studio, how can I debug/test if the package works as intended?

Debug menu doesn't allow me to start debugging. Is this because I'm not seeing anything in my solution explorer? I can't seem to find a solution/project attached to this dtsx file though. I have simply saved the changes after removing the errors it had and have no way of testing.

I found that Double-clicking a `.dtsx` file should launch the `DTExec GUI`, but in my case it just open visual studio in Designer view.

Comment: Yes, pretty sure it needs to be in a project or a solution. There may be project level variables or parameters required. Typically I debug packages by running them and inspecting the input and output data.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new SQL Server Integration Services project and adding the .dtsx file as an existing item?

Comment: Thank you, creating a new project did it